# A different word for "Rhyming Dictionary"

Tags: synonyms

Is there a different word, a synonym or neologism for "Rhyming Dictionary"?

I mean something like Rhyming + thesaurus?

Comment: A "neologism" is just a new word. You are looking for a synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These have always been known as "rhyming dictionaries." Since they do not generally have definitions, and simply list homonyms and homophones, they are more akin to orthographies.